# Timber/WooCommerce 3.3.x issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, timber

I've been using Timber for a while now for my WordPress theme development and love it. However, I've recently come up against an issue I've not seen before. Please note that the site in question was developed using WC 3.2.6 and Timber 1.7.0 and everything worked perfectly. The project got sidelined for a bit and is now set to roll out, so I updated all the plugins and came across an issue where it appears as if WooCommerce changed when it initializes (maybe?).

I don't use WooCommerce much at all, so I'm hoping this is something simple and obvious that I'm just missing.

Using WC 3.2.6 WC pages use their own templates and any overwrites I have in my theme directory, and non-WC pages use Twig templates as expected. *After* the update, WC uses Twig templates instead of it's own - which needless to say completely breaks my site. I use a pattern to Timber/WordPress development where everything goes through the main functions.php file, which includes a theme functions object where the render template is decided - the only php files I have in the theme directory are those associated with specific custom templates (gallery.php, staff-listing.php, etc..) and the index.php file. They look like this:

```
$data = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render($data['template'], $data, 600);
```

My base functions.php file includes the following:

```
if(!class_exists('Timber')){
    add_action('admin_notices', function(){
        print("<div class='error'><h1>Please activate the Timber plugin</h1></div>");
    });
    return;
}

require_once('includes/ThemeFunctions.php');
$fn = new ThemeFunctions();
// ...
add_filter('timber_context', array($fn,'addToContext'));
//...
```

The ThemeFunctions file includes the following methods:

```
    public function addToContext(array $context){
        if(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX){
            return $context;
        }
        $context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
    // ...
        $context['template'] = $this->getRenderTemplate($context['posts']);
    // ...
        return $context;
    }

    private function getRenderTemplate(ArrayObject $post){
        $post = isset($post[0]) ? $post[0] : null;
        $tpl = !empty($post) ? get_page_template_slug($post->ID) : null;
        if(empty($tpl)){
            $tpl = 'index';
        }
        if(is_404()){
            $tpl = '404';
        }
        if(is_front_page()){
            $tpl = 'home';
        }
        if(is_home() || is_archive() || is_search()){
            $tpl = 'archive';
        }
        if(is_single()){
            $tpl = 'single';
        }
        $tpl = str_replace(array('.','/',' ','php','"',"'"), '', $tpl);
        if(!file_exists($this->_themeDir.'views/'.$tpl.$this->_fileExt) || !ctype_alnum(str_replace(array('-','_'), '', $tpl))){
            return '404'.$this->_fileExt;
        }
        return esc_attr($tpl).$this->_fileExt;
    }
```

Each of my Twig templates includes a data-template attribute on the opening body tag, which is how I know that 3.2.6 was rendering WC templates - that data attribute wasn't there. Now it is.

### TL;DR

Am I missing something or was there a change in WC at or around version 3.3.0 that changed when the plugin initializes and necessitates a change to the timing or priority of the get_context filter? I’m looking through the changelog and source code, but was hoping someone knew off the top of their head where I should look. Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else is running into a similar issue, the cause of the problem is the hook used to add WooCommerce support to the theme. I usually use the 'init' hook to add all my theme support, including WC. For v 3.3.0 and up, it appears as though the init hook is fired too late in the process and WC support has to be added using the 'after_setup_theme' hook.